# Mapping association of child model

Tags: ruby

I have a Stories with a has_many relationship to chapters
Chapter has_many relationship with pages

I would like to return a list of pages on my Stories object with a method Stories.pages

```
def pages
  self.chapters.map do |c| c.pages end
end
```

This is not returning a list of lists 
ive resorted to doing this

```
def pages
  pages =[]
  self.chapters.each do |c|
    c.pages.each do |p|
      pages << p
    end
  end
end
```

I'm new to ruby, with php and c# background, i know i could do this with an association directly between stories and pages or create custom query (INNER JOIN).

But would like to wrap my head around map, reduce methods a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create your own custom method, Rails already provides this as [`has_many :through` associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
  has_many :pages, :through => :chapters
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out such an obvious an answer. got hung up on trying to use the map method

Comment: @user1760852 That said if you were doing pure Ruby you'd probably want to call [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to turn your list of lists into a single, flat list.